# How can I fill the color of text from left to right in Flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, text, colors, right-to-left

I want to create animation for Text.Fill Text color from left to right.

[animation 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOFtR.png)[animation 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1nb1.png)

Comment: refer [this](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_text_kit) package hope its helpful to you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use this package [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_text_kit) you can also change the colors there